# Program ignoring if-statements during while-loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I am writing a python program that updates coordinates using a given equation: `(x,y) = (ax-by, ay+bx)`. This should be done for each step (`n`) which comprises of `c+1` amounts of micro steps. So basically for each of the 4 steps I am updating the position 3 times.

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'findPosition' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER s
#  2. INTEGER x0
#  3. INTEGER y0
#  4. INTEGER a
#  5. INTEGER b
#  6. INTEGER c
#  7. INTEGER l
#  8. INTEGER n
#

def findPosition(s, x0, y0, a, b, c, l, n):
    # Write your code here
    xf = yf = 0
    t = 0
    while (n > 0):
        while (t <= c):
            xf = (a * x0) - (b * y0)
            yf = (a * y0) + (b * x0)
            if (xf >= s):
                xf = xf - s
            if (yf >= s):
                yf = yf - s
            if (xf < 0):
                xf = xf + s
            if (yf < 0):
                yf = yf + s
            x0 = xf
            y0 = yf
            #print (xf, yf)
            t = t + 1
        t = 0
        n = n - 1
    return (xf, yf)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()
    a = int(first_multiple_input[0])
    b = int(first_multiple_input[1])
    c = int(first_multiple_input[2])
    l = int(first_multiple_input[3])
 
    second_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()
    s = int(second_multiple_input[0])
    x0 = int(second_multiple_input[1])
    y0 = int(second_multiple_input[2])
    n = int(second_multiple_input[3])
 
    result = findPosition(s, x0, y0, a, b, c, l, n)

    fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')
    fptr.close()
```

The problem is that my code ignores my `if` statements at a certain time in the program (during micro-step 1 of step 3).
The output I should get is:

```
(4, 7)  (1, 18) (7 ,14)
(0, 12) (11, 1) (21, 13)
(6, 1)  (11, 8) (14, 4)
(1, 22) (3, 22) (7, 1)
```

What I actually get is:

```
(4, 7)  (1, 18)  (7, 14)
(0, 12)  (11, 1)  (21, 13)
(6, 24)  (11, 31)  (14, 50)
(1, 91)  (-66, 160)  (-269, 231)
```

This is for input: `a=2`, `b=1`, `c=2`, `l=1`, `s=23`, `x0=3`, `y0=2`, `n=4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not ignoring your `if` statements.  Your `if` statements just do not reflect what you need.  In the 6th step, xf,yf become (29,47).  47 > 23, so you subtract 23 to get 24.  You do not allow for the case when xf or yf is greater than TWICE s.  What you want is the modulo operator, as below.  Oh, and please note that, in Python, `if`, `while` and `return` statements do not need parentheses.

```
def findPosition(s, x0, y0, a, b, c, l, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for t in range(c+1):
            xf = ((a * x0) - (b * y0)) % s
            yf = ((a * y0) + (b * x0)) % s
            x0 = xf
            y0 = yf
            print (i, t, c, s, xf, yf)
    return xf, yf
```

Comment: Thank you very much!